# Nginx load balancer configuration

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

My requirement is to load balance two ESB web services running in two separate nodes `(10.110.6.29, 10.110.6.45)` I'm using nginx and is installed in 10.110.6.45. Basically when I send a request to `10.110.6.45 (port 80)` it should be equally load balanced to both nodes.

Below is the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

```
user  www;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;    

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream esbhnbwso2.hnb.lk{
    server 10.110.6.45:8280;
    server 10.110.6.29:8280;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://esbhnbwso2.hnb.lk;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

}
```

when I try to call the service `http://10.110.6.45/hnbceftapi` I'm getting the below nginx page.
What am I doing wrong? any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 27 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <title>404 Not Found</title>
   </head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
      <center>
         <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
      </center>
      <hr/>
      <center>nginx/1.14.2</center>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some internet reading, I was able to make nginx work. These were my finding, thought 
of sharing these.

I had to enable linux internal firewall with the below commands.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --permanent  --zone=public --add-service=https
```

These commands basically will create a public zone and allow http(80), https(443) traffic.

Can verify the allowed ports by running below command.

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

Had to run the below command to allow the httpd - http daemon (Apache web server which nginx runs) to make http communication.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

These configuration were required because the distibution I was working on was a Security Enhanced Linux (SELinux). I'm not a system admin hence I was not aware of these configurations.